# Distinguish multiple font inside same Text Layer

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I've created a very basic script that allows the user to replace a specific font in all the document (even LayerSets) by another one.

A practice example: I want to substitute all Arial-Bold by Arial-Italic, but some of the TextLayers have Arial-Bold and Arial-Regular inside the same Layer, how can make that the script only changes the Arial-Bold part of the TextLayer and not the whole layer?

Code I'm currently using:

```
var inFont = prompt("write inFont","Write inFont");
var outFont = prompt("write outFont","Write outFont");

app.preferences.typeUnits = TypeUnits.PIXELS;
var doc = app.activeDocument;

function changeFonts(target){
    var layers = target.layers;
    for(var i=0;i<layers.length;i++){
        if(layers[i].typename == "LayerSet"){
            changeFonts(layers[i]);
        } else {
            if((layers[i].kind == LayerKind.TEXT) && (layers[i].textItem.font == inFont)) {
                layers[i].textItem.font = outFont;
            };
        };
    };
};

changeFonts(doc);
```

Comment: I've already found the solution: https://github.com/iamdarrenhall/list-fonts

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you would have to crawl through the text and look at each individual character. Here is an article that that talks about formatting specific character ranges. [Formatting text ranges](http://blogs.adobe.com/cssdk/2011/01/formatting-text-ranges-in-photoshop.html).
You could use something like this to loop through the text one character at a time, check the formatting and change it if needed. I can't think of any other way to approach this.

Comment: Thanks for your time TinMonkey, I'll look that!